# How to make div text responsive on widget resize

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on widgets using gridstack. The problem I'm facing is when I resize the widget the text is not flexible.

I want the text to change it size with the widget resize. I'm stuck on it from few days and don't know what to do. I did media queries but it didn't working.

More over I'm using angularjs and bootstrap.

```
<div id="widget" class="img-background" onclick="$('#filePhoto').click()" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
<h1 style="font-size: 4em; color: #DCDCDC;left:2em; text-align: center;">Drag Image</h1>
</div>
```

I want that when i resize the widget then drag Image text should enlarge with widget enlargement.

Comment: maybe you search for: https://github.com/marcj/css-element-queries

Answer (score 2):

You can use `vw` unit of `font-size` in css for this

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sanchitpatiyal95/s0po1c80/

```
h1{
  font-size: 20vw;
}
```

Comment: No, i dnt want to Resize the width of the browser window to see how the font-size of h1 changes.But i want that if i resize the widgetthen the text sholu change.

Comment: width size was just a example when you will resize widget then also it will change. You can try

Comment: Basically it’s with respect to the outer container